# try_files $uri and utf-8 filenames

Tags: unicode

I'm using python to generate my website as static files and uploading them to the webserver. How should I be handling utf-8 filenames?

I have a utf-8 filename 가요.html which returns a 404 using:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html
```

With strace nginx is looking for the UTF-8 bytes in octal:

```
\352\260\200\354\232\224.html
```

I tried $request_uri instead of $uri and I see nginx looking for the url encoded:

```
%EA%B0%80%EC%9A%94.html
```

가요.html exists in the directory nginx is looking. Can I solve this in nginx without using $request_uri and url encoding the filenames on the server? Having nginx correctly find "가요.html" by assuming utf-8 encoding here?

EDIT - 
This isn't an nginx problem? I just did a touch of 你好 and nginx served it correctly:

```
[pid 228568] recvfrom(3, "GET /%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD "..., 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 847
[pid 228568] stat("/webroot/\344\275\240\345\245\275", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

Same setup, same directory, stat with octals reported by strace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that files created on a Mac with Korean filenames are saved in decomposed form whereas everyone else uses precomposed. Same looking filename with two different unicode values.

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1422374.html