# Nginx mapping Japanese URL to encoded file/folder names

Tags: nginx, urlencode, cjk

I have file names written in encoded format.  For example, this URL /2012年日本の旅/ is saved as: /2012%e5%b9%b4%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e3%81%ae%e6%97%85/index.html on Nginx server.

But Nginx does not serve the URL.

If I change the folder name in the Japanese language, it works. I mean /2012年日本の旅/index.html

Comment: Remember to show your nginx.conf, so future visitors can tell whether they have the same problem, or whether this is specific to just your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542750/try-files-uri-and-utf-8-filenames) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637) and assuming you are using e.g. `try_files` to serve files, simply use `$request_uri` instead of `$uri`. Without your nginx.conf that's about all one can say.